# Extending the validation range expression to facilitate OR logic

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my class definition, lets say I want to allow the value 100 to be entered, in addition to 0-20 being valid, can this be acheived with a simple "or 100" logic to the expression?

```
>     [DisplayName("VAT %")]
>     [Range(0, 20)]
>     //[Range(100, 100)] tried this but cannot duplicate range expression
>     [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}%")]
>     public decimal VAT { get; set; }
```

Comment: Create your own [validation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-attributes).

Answer (score 1):

OK I think its easy enough, i'll remove the "[Range(0, 20)]" from the class and simply add logic into the Validation() method server side. Don't think it can be done class side here unless maybe a regex